# Strategy for managing individuals' SSH access from Ansible hub

Tags: ssh, ansible

My team has an Ansible hub, from which we manage several nodes. To do so, we ssh to the hub, and sudo to a shared "ansible" user. This user has an ssh keypair, which all the nodes have in their authorized_keys file.

This works, but it means that everyone has access to all nodes at all times.

What I'd like is some approach that lets us restrict users so they can only access certain nodes. We could add/remove individuals' keys from each node's authorized_keys as needed, but this seems like a lot to manage. I'd like something that's easy to manage, so that we can quickly authorize/deauthorize a user for different nodes.

Does anyone have a strategy like this? I was thinking of using [signed ssh keys](https://linux-audit.com/granting-temporary-access-to-servers-using-signed-ssh-keys/) to grant temporary access, but haven't really explored it.

Comment: It's time to move to AWX/Tower.

Comment: Rundeck could be a good, cheap open-source solution to this too.

Answer (score 1):

You have Ansible - so there is a quick solution - use Ansible for that...

If all users on the hub have a public key, you could use that public keys and the ansible user to publish the user-public-key to the target hosts.

If you want to restrict access per machine you could configure the list of users per host or hostgroup and only populate that public keys to that hosts in that group. Also removing a user from a target host is easy that way, either using a map and a template (instead of appending the pubkey) or build a negative list.

So the user can hop from the hub to the target machine directly without the Ansible user.